# Python range().count() is like "contains()" (?)

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm looking for verification for the following

`count(i)` function of Python `range()` counts the number of occurrences of the value `i` in the range it runs on, and thus returns either 0 or 1-- nothing else.

found no hint to anything otherwise in the docs read and the runs I made. wanna verify still-- a bit odd.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `range()` objects conform to the [Sequence ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence), and that ABC has a `count()` method.

So it is there just for completeness sake, so that the object [qualifies as a sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence).

Also see the following link that it states the methods `range` has due to it being part of the Sequence ABC  https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq